# Xpath and condition

Tags: java, xpath

How can i get values of nodes if two nodes are is present under parent node.
Eg: I have the following Xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Services xmlns="http://sample.schema.com/abc">
    <service>
        <name>Sample</name>
        <uri>/v9.0/sample.123.com
        </uri>
    </service>
    <service>
        <name>Sample 2</name>
    </service>
    <service>
        <name>Sample 3</name>
        <uri>/v9.0/sample3.123.com
        </uri>
    </service>
    <service>
        <name>Sample 4</name>
        <uri>/v9.0/sample4.123.com
        </uri>
    </service>
    <service>
        <name>Sample 5</name>
        <uri>/v9.0/sample5.123.com
        </uri>
    </service>
    <service>
        <name>Sample 6</name>

    </service>
    <service>
        <name>Sample 7</name>
        <uri>/v9.0/sample7.123.com
            </uri>
    </service>
    <service>
        <name>Sample 8</name>
    </service>
</Services>
```

**My Code:**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
public class SimpleXpath {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException,
            SAXException, IOException, XPathExpressionException {
          DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            domFactory.setNamespaceAware(false); // never forget this!
            DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse("testService1.xml");
            XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
            XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//Services/service[(name) and (uri)/text()]");
            Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
           for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            String value=nodes.item(i).getNodeValue();
               System.out.println(" output : "+i+"  "+value); 
            }
    }

}
```

I want to read the values of name and url from th above xml, If the name and uri is present under the service node.
We can see that some of the service node only contains the name. I want to avoid those one. My xpath expression gives null value as output.

How can i get the "text" of name and uri if service contains both?

Can i get the output as name as first and uri as second using an xpath(If both present under service)?

Thnanks a lot.

John

Comment: `/Services/service/uri[text()]/..` maybe?

Comment: Does `/Services/service[name and uri]` work?

Comment: Guys i got them separatley throgh this `//Services/service[(name) and (uri)]/uri/text()` xpath O/P  output : 0  /v9.0/sample.123.com
  
 output : 1  /v9.0/sample3.123.com
  
 output : 2  /v9.0/sample4.123.com
  
 output : 3  /v9.0/sample5.123.com
  
 output : 4  /v9.0/sample7.123.com
      
There is only 5 case matching you can see the xml the rest of the service tag contains onlu the name.

Comment: Can i get the output as output : Sample 0 output :/v9.0/sample.123.com

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you could just use simpler xpath: `//Services/service[name and uri]`. Then NodeList returns you a list of `service` elements. You could iterate other its children and find elements named `name` and `uri`, then take their text values. Or you could create two more xpath expressions like this:

```
        XPathExpression exprName = xpath.compile("normalize-space(name)");
        String name = (String)exprName.evaluate(serviceNode, XPathConstants.STRING);
```

and the same for uri.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all....
The following code fulfills the requirement.
If there any other option to improve the quality please suggest.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException,
            SAXException, IOException, XPathExpressionException {
          DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            domFactory.setNamespaceAware(false); // never forget this!
            DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse("testService1.xml");
            XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
            XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//Services/service[(name) and (uri)]/name/text()");
            Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;

            XPathExpression expr1 = xpath.compile("//Services/service[(name) and (uri)]/uri/text()");
            Object result1 = expr1.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            NodeList nodes1 = (NodeList) result1;

           for (int i = 0; i < nodes1.getLength()&&i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
               String value=nodes.item(i).getNodeValue();
            String value1=nodes1.item(i).getNodeValue();
               System.out.println(" output : "+i+"  "+value+ " "+ value1); 
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This xpath select elements that has 2 children

```
//*[count(*)=2]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for(int j=0; j<children.getLength();j++) {
   if (children.item(j) instanceof Element == false)
       continue;

   NamedNodeMap n = children.item(j).getAttributes();
   passwordTagAttr=(Attr) n.getNamedItem("name");
   passwordTagAttr=(Attr) n.getNamedItem("uri");
   passwordTag=stopTagAttr.getValue();  
   passwordList.add(passwordTag);                   
}
```